# Converse proof for random coding capacity of AVC

Tags: proof-techniques, information-theory, coding-theory

I want to see the converse proof for the random coding (shared randomness) capacity of AVC. All I can find online is [Csiszar Narayan's AVC](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=2627) paper which looks at deterministic coding. Further, the proof itself is quite dense (using Lemma 2 in the paper).

I am wondering if there is any work that proves the converse of AVC random coding capacity (shared randomness). If anyone can write the proof here then that works as well. I am ok with a proof for deterministic coding capacity of AVC as well if it is different from the above-mentioned paper.

Comment: Some proofs are technical. There's no way around it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus How about the proof for random coding (shared randomness) ? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrarily_varying_channel#Capacity_of_randomized_AVCs) gives a reference. Have you checked it?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks a lot. 'Reliable Communication Under Channel Uncertainty' gives a comprehensive survey that helped me find the desired proof. Don't know why it didn't show up in google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete proof appears in Blackwell, Breiman and Thomasian, [The Capacities of Certain Channel Classes Under Random Coding](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177705783). This paper is linked from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrarily_varying_channel#Capacity_of_randomized_AVCs) on AVCs.